# I Install Ubuntu in a usb drive

Tags: boot, usb, boost

I Install Ubuntu in a usb drive, all went well, it boots perfect but it seems to be "laggy" im sure that the usb maybe not be to fast. Is there anything i can do to make it faster ?

Comment: What do you mean by laggy? Laggy as in the mouse is slow/jumpy, laggy as in it takes a long time to load anything? Without more explanation as to what you mean by "laggy" we can't really help you.

Comment: Yes sorry.. no laggy.. it is slow to open for example settings or monzilla, sometimes the screen blures and i wait 2 min to respone. it fails to laod on time. My pc is core duo 2 Ghz 4 gb ram

Comment: Ah, yes. That's most likely because you have a slower USB stick. Running Ubuntu off a USB stick will be much slower than installing it and using it from there, simply because USB is slower than SATA in most cases.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to make it faster ?

Comment: Other than using a faster USB stick with USB 3 or using a lighter distribution of Ubuntu like Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu, or Lubuntu - nothing that I can think of off the top of my head. Sorry.

Comment: before i install it in this usb i boot it from the same usb and i choose "try ubuntu" in this mode all worked perfectly! no lags no nothing.

Comment: Was it on the same machine with the same USB stick? Have you installed anything or saved anything on the USB stick?

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck is probably the USB key read/write speed.
Consider using a faster USB key or an external hard drive.
Here is a comparison of theorical max data transfer speeds.
The actual speeds are usually much less.

- USB 1.1 = 1.5 MB/s
- Firefire 400 = 50 MB/s
- USB 2.0 = 60 MB/s
- FireWire 800 = 100 MB/s
- USB 3.0 = 625 MB/s
- eSATA = 750 MB/s

Comment: Is there anything to make it faster in this case? i use a usb 2.0 and a usb 16gb

Comment: If it could be done with a USB 2.0 thumb drive, we'd use the same speed-up techniques with SATA and you'd really be seeing some lag.